# convert factor levels back into original character values

Tags: r, model

i built a predictive model classifying persons into two categories having <=50k  and >50k  income

but as i open my file in excel or r to see final predictions i see in place of my values only the levels ( 1 and 2 ) which i assigned in first place to simplify process

please tell me how to retain my original values represented by  levels rather than the levels

Here is the  outline i followed

this is my target variable  income.group 
here it is the initial state

str   (train_gbW7HTd $Income.Group)

chr [1:32561] "<=50K" "<=50K" "<=50K" "<=50K" "<=50K" "<=50K" "<=50K" ...

now to apply decision trees i encoded my target variable into levels 1 and 2 
i used the following code 
train$Income.Group <- match(train$Income.Group,unique(train$Income.Group))
i got

table(train$Income.Group)

```
1     2
```

24720  7841

i build decision tree like this 
set.seed(333)

> fit <- rpart (Income.Group ~.,data = train, method = "class", control =  rpart. control( minsplit = 20, minbucket  = 100, maxdepth = 10, xval = 5)
>        + )

make predictions 
pred <- predict(fit,test,type = "class")

pred_train <- predict(fit,train,type = "class")

confusionMatrix (pred_train,train$Income.Group)

saved my file 
solution.frame <- data.frame(ID = test$ID, Income.Group = pred)

write.csv(solution.frame,file = "final_solution.csv")

but my final csv file has levels 1 and 2 representing final predictions and not <=50k and >50k which i actually want.
please tell me how to proceed .
thanks in advance 
 i already used
 solution.frame$Income.Group <- ifelse(solution.frame$Income.Group =="1","<=50k",">50k")

but it gave single value >50k to entire column of Income.Group

Please tell me what to do as i m stuck at this step and unable to complete my model submission.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ifelse:

```
train$Income.Group<-ifelse(train$Income.Group=="1","<=50K",">50K")
```

Comment: i used the same code earlier while  encoding and it gave only a single value  1 to all  rows of income.group dataset . i used the same code again and all my values were converted into >50k . please tell me is there any other way out . as i use this if else anytime it only assigns a single value to all of the column. thanks in advance , pls comment

Comment: I just read your code again. First thing you code encode your Income.group as a factor variable by using train$Income.Group<-as.factor(train$Income.Group) and then try to write predictions to file.